# ML.NET web API use data from file

Tags: ml.net

I am following this sample
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net

I need to load data from file. This code use stream

```
//Deserialize HTTP request JSON body
            var body = http.Request.Body as Stream;
            var input = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Sentiment.Input>(body);

            // Predict
            var prediction = predEngine.Predict(input);
```

I have this

```
    IDataView data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<HeartData>(@"C:HeartTest.csv", hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ';');
                IEnumerable<HeartData> heartDataEnumerable = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<HeartData>(data, reuseRowObject: false);
    
                foreach (var heartData in heartDataEnumerable)
                {
  byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(heartData.ToString());
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                //var input 
                var input = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<HeartData>(stream);
                var prediction = predEngine.Predict(input);
}
```

Error when convert to var input
How do I use heartData? How can I convert hearData to stream?

Thanks